# Why does Math.random() in Java returns a double in [0, 1) instead of other intervals?

Tags: algorithm, random

I bumped into this question in my AP Computer Science course yesterday.

Ask my CS teacher-> He don't know it.

Search the web-> Loosely related answers.

Scholarly articles-> Try, but can't understand.

I guess this question relates with the algorithm of random number generation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's down to the algorithm but I'd say it's been designed that way so that you can manipulate the range in the easiest possible way : by multiplying it with another integer. There doesn't seem to be any specific reason apart from convenience and standards in other Random functions.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a number in [0, 1) because this makes the most sense. It is easy to convert to other intervals [low, high) with a simple formula:

```
low + Math.random() * (high - low)
```

What else would you choose that has equally easy conversion properties?

Comment: Bold statement that it "makes the most sense". `Math.random(low, high)` would make more sense and minimize all the bias bugs that appear because of the current interface.

Comment: @EmilVikström I mean most sense for a fixed interval.

Answer (score 0):

There are constraints on the allowable bit patterns that can represent a double, so you cannot just generate a load of random bits and expect it to be a valid double.  There are things like `NaN` and `INFINITY` as well as completely invalid patterns.

Given that, then the easiest way to generate a double is to do a division.  The code is already there to do all the work needed.  In order to get the finest grain of double we need to divide two large numbers with a low result.  That means something like:

```
random_double = random_integer / (1.0 * max_random)
```

Since most random integer generators generate in the range [0, max_random) then the resulting double is in the range [0, 1.0).

$0.02

Comment: That should be `random_integer / (max_random + 1.0)` in order to avoid producing 1.0. (Or you need to say that the rsulting interval is closed rather than half-open.) As a side-benefit, the divisor is now a power of 2 so the division is exact and there are faster ways to compute it.

Comment: Even if you did know you'd get a valid number, it wouldn't really be useful. Like, trying to convert a random double into the result of a fair die roll would be gnarly.